# Start service without activity extended

Tags: android, service, android-activity, fragment

I want to start a Service in my class

```
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
```

It previously went just fine, when I extended the Activity superclass, but since I have to extend Fragment I am having a problem..

I implemented the OnClicklistener to the LayoutOne class, so I want to start a service in it, but it gives me an error on the new Intent line and the startServcie line.. any idea how I can fix this?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.bGo:

if (mStartGo) {
mButton.setText(“Stop going boy”);
mStartGo = false;

Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartGoService.class);
Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
intent.putExtra(“MESSENGER”, messenger);
startService(intent);
//…
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), StartGoService.class);
Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
intent.putExtra(“MESSENGER”, messenger);
v.getContext().startService(intent);
```

Since it is a View's onClick() method, you should be able to use the Context that was used to create the View.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... Getting Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.viewpager/com.test.viewpager.StartGoService}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.viewpager.StartGoService
 as error :( PS I am sorry, but don't undestand what you mean with: Make sure to call getActivity() after your Fragment has been attached to an Activity.. What I now did is tested your code above instead of the 4 lines I had..